# User has to reset password each time

Tags: chatter, login, passwords, forgot-your-password

I have a user who is not able to login on Salesforce.

His password has been reset, he was able to login but after he logs out he cannot relogin again.
The user has to reset his password each time to be able to login.

Please note that the user is using the correct url and username (not the reset password url). There is no IP restriction and the user has even tried to login on different browsers and computers but the problem is still same.

Could you please help me on this.

Comment: Is he the only user facing that problem? Or are there other users (maybe from the same profile)?

Comment: he is the only user having this issue

Comment: Interesting. Did you had a look at the login history of the user? Maybe for some reason, he is locking himself from Salesforce?

Comment: e.g. for example - s/he has an api client  associated with the user seat that is configured with the wrong password and it is attempting to login repeatedly on some time interval and hitting the 6 invalid login attempts

Comment: The login history shows 'success' only when the user reset his password and login, The invalid password is not recorded

I have created a dummy account for the user with the same profile and settings. The user is able to login with the dummy account

Comment: Sometimes clearing the cache ans cookies helps.